# What is the function of oxyphilic cells in the parathyroid?

Tags: endocrinology, histology

Apart from the chief cells, which produce and secrete parathyroid hormone (PTH), the parathyroid gland has another type of cells, which are large and fewer in number, have small, dark nuclei and an acidophilic cytoplasm with many mitochondria. These cells increase in number with aging. As far as I know, we still have no knowledge of what role they perform, or why they increase with age.

Is this true, or are there already some concrete ideas about this?